# DiscordJs cascade of awaitMessages

Tags: discord.js

I'm new to the discordjs package and I've been digging around but for the last 2 days I'm stuck at this.

What I'm trying to achieve is "questionnaire" that will guide the user through some questions. An example would be:
User types: !askOrder

- Q: Do you want red wine or white wine?
- A: white wine
- Q: You want white wine. Do you prefer a verdejo or a rueda?
- A: rueda
- Q: A rueda it's. Do you want it at room temperature or chill?
- A: room temperature.

What I've is:

```
msg.author.send('Do you want red wine or white wine?');        
        msg.author.send(WineText)
        .then((systemMsg) => { 
            systemMsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
              max: 1,
              time: 5000,
              errors: ['time'],
        }).then((collected) => {
            systemMsg.channel.send(`You want ${collected.first().content}. Do you prefer a verdejo or a rueda?`);
            collected.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
                max: 1,
                time: 10000
            });
        })then((collected2) => {
            systemMsg.channel.send(`A ${collected2.first().content} it's. Do you want it at room temperature or chill? `);
        }).catch((err) => {
            return;
        });
```

But it simply stops after it asks the second questions, not capturing/collecting the second answer. What is it that Im doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is put all of the questions (and answers) in an array, wrap those statements in a function, and loop them over an iteration like this:

```
    let i = 0; let questions = ['Q1', 'Q2'];

    function askQuestion() {
        const filter = m => m.author.id == message.author.id;

        message.channel.send(questions[i]).then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 120000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(async collected => {

                    //do stuff
                    message.channel.send(`answer was ${collected.first().content}`);

                    i++; //increase iteration
                    if (i === questions.length) return;
                    else askQuestion();
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    //timed out
                });
        });
    }
    askQuestion();
```

It helps clean your code a little bit. You can change them as you see fit.

I made a bot that ask questions just like this, you can view the code [here](https://github.com/Raphilia/watame/blob/master/commands/faction.js)

Answer (score 0):

You structured your awaitMessages events wrong:

```
msg.author.send('Do you want red wine or white wine?');        
        msg.author.send(WineText)
        .then((systemMsg) => { 
            systemMsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
              max: 1,
              time: 5000,
              errors: ['time']
        }).then((collected) => {
            systemMsg.channel.send(`You want ${collected.first().content}. Do you prefer a verdejo or a rueda?`);
            collected.first().channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
                max: 1,
                time: 10000
            }).then((collected2) => {
                systemMsg.channel.send(`A ${collected2.first().content} it's. Do you want it at room temperature or chill? `);
        }).catch((err) => {
            return;
        });
        });
        });
```

There were 2 crucial errors you made:

(1) You sent a message to `collected.channel`. However, `collected` is a `collection` of messages, and doesn't have a channel property. To send it to the channel, just do `collected.first().channel`, since `collected.first()` is a message.
(2) You were missing two `})`s at the end of your code, because of the `then`s that you included and never closed.